# Trying to test Google In-app-billing, but has strange behaviour

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a developer account and have published my app on Google Play. After that I started working on Ads and In-app-purchases. For the in-app-purchases I am using this repo: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

I tested it first by using Androids test product id (android.test.purchased), and it worked as expected. Using that test Id, I could buy the product and could also check if the product was bought.

Then I created a merchant account using the developer console, and also added a product to it. I found the merchant ID and the product ID to be used in the app.

Instead of using the android test product id, used mine as the LICENCE_KEY and added the MERCHANT_ID (which i did not use with the test product id). Here is the BillingProcessor constructor:

`bp = new BillingProcessor(MainActivity.this, LICENCE_KEY, MERCHANT_ID, MainActivity.this);`

Lastly I rolled out this new apk version to alpha, and added a gmail address for another account I have in the closed alpha testers list.
Now here comes the strange part: As the new account i opted in on the alpha on my computer. In the Google Play app on the phone I switched users to the new account and downloaded my app. I checked that this was the right version and it was. I also checked that the app was in the library inside "my apps and games" for the right user. I then tried the in-app-purchase, but I get a window with a text saying "please sign in to your google account, authentication required". I have seen similar error messages on SO, but they had forgot to add emails in testers list etc. and I know thats not the case for me.

I even tried creating a brand new gmail account, added it in the testers list and then used a new phone with the brand new account just to be met by the same error message.
At this moment I have no clue what is going on, so I ask in the support chat inside the dev console. They did not know why it did not work, so I had to wait for the answer through email. days later they sent me an email and said that I should try clearing the cache and cookies for chrome on my phone. I did and still no fix. 
So if anyone has experienced the same, or know any nice solutions for this it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Rolled out app as closed beta instead of closed alpha and it works fine now. I have no Idea why :P